# In shopify want to get the products varient color name in my dropdown

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am new to liquid how to get the name of all the color varients of my product in select tag

Answer (score 2):

Generally inside the `product.liquid` it would be something like:

```
  {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
    {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
  <div class="options">
  <div>{{ option.name }}</div>
      <select class="product-variants {{ option.name | handleize }} option-{{option.position}}" data-url="{{ product.url }}">
        {% for value in option.values %}
          <option {% if option.selected_value == value %}selected{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
  </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

So if you had variants of "`Size`" and "`Color`" it would output something like:

`Size`:
Dropdown Menu options below

- S
- M
- L
- XL

`Color`:
Dropdown Menu options below

- Red
- Black
- Blue
- Green

If my solution helped you, please like and accept it as a solution!

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer just wanna know that how to fetch the product by different varient and add use this dropdown options as filter.

Comment: on cart page or listing page?

Comment: on collection page I think its listing

Comment: try this app for easy filter options on the collection listing page
https://apps.shopify.com/ultimate-search-and-filter-1

Comment: the code you gave can i use it in a collection page

Comment: <select id="Car">
      <option value="">No color</option>
      {% for col in products.options %}  
        {% if current_col contains col %}
      <option value="{{ col | handle }}">{{ col }} </option>
{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</select>

Comment: this will work on the product single page or on products loop

Comment: <select id="Car">
      <option value="">No color</option>
      {% for col in products.options %}  
        {% if current_col contains col %}
      <option value="{{ col | handle }}">{{ col }} </option>
{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</select>

Comment: want to get the color from product varients

Comment: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Add-color-swatches-to-products/m-p/616427